# How to look up data from an ul li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My error that I present in adding a data search engine from a  tags in specifies (`ul -> li`) is:

when I add a text in the search engine, the search input disappears

```js
    jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('li').each(function() {
          options.push({
            value: $(this).val(),
            text: $(this).text()
          });
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
          var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
          var search = $.trim($(this).val());
          var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

          $.each(options, function(i) {
            var option = options[i];
            if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
              $(select).append(
                $('<li>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
              );
            }
          });
        });
      });
    };

    /*$(function() {
      $('.options').filterByText($('input'));
    });*/
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}
/*
.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}
*/
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.search {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="search"><input type="text" id="search"></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 3</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 4</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 5</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 6</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 7</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 8</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 9</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 10</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 11</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 12</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 13</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 14</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 15</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 16</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 17</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 18</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 19</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 20</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 21</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 22</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 23</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 24</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 25</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 26</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 27</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 28</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 29</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 30</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 31</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 32</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>B</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>C</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>D</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>H</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Other</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

My idea is to show only the data that is coinciding in the search engine if I search for an existing specific word that shows me only that record and that the others do not show

I was looking for some other example code and only found this code on the web

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Can you explain to me, please, what I'm doing wrong in the code.

Comment: I had a quick search, I guess you can find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52705677/10512904) [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975738/10512904)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple jsfiddle, works flawless with the second link I posted [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/89ae3snf/)

You have to remove the input out of the ul or it will be filtered, or you handle it differently

```
<input type="text" id="search"> <!-- not in ul > li -->
```